# Converting an NgbDate to moment for formatting purposes: issue with first month assigned as 0 vs 1

Tags: angular, momentjs

I have an Ngb-Datepicker that allows for a range selection. I'm using moment.js to convert the NgbDate into a moment object so that I can covert and output the format as I'd like: ex. Wed Jan 23.

I realized that NgbDates give January a 1 value and moment gives January a 0, so I used `myMoment.subtract(1, 'months')` to resolve that (before the dates were being outputted as a month later).

My issue now is that moment still treats the number of days from the original month the same. So when I try and select a date range from say Jan. 1 - Jan 31, it doesn't work because anything past the 28th is invalid.

The 29-31st can still be selected, but when I try and output it using the `formatDate()` function, it gets treated as an invalid date because moment still treats it as being in the following month (February) -- you'll see that the "to:" label at the bottom won't have a date added to it.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtrvjr?file=app%2Fdatepicker-range.ts

Console output when I log my converted moment:
[image: Console output]

Date conversion function:

```
// Convert date to "Mon Feb 01" format
formatDate(date: NgbDate) {
  const myMoment: moment.Moment = moment(date);

  // NgbDates use 1 for Jan, Moement uses 0, must substract 1 month for proper date conversion
  var convertedMoment = myMoment.subtract(1, 'months');

  if (convertedMoment.isValid()) {
    return convertedMoment.format('ddd MMM DD');
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Template that uses the function:

```
From: {{ formatDate(fromDate) }}
```

```
To: {{ formatDate(toDate) }}
```

Comment: Ngb-datepicker use by defect NgbDateStructure, moment use JavaScript date Object. I think you can use NgbDateAdapter to work directy as DateObject. it's just the example in https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter. the only thing you need is add providers: [{provide: NgbDateAdapter, useClass: NgbDateNativeAdapter}] in your providers

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a solution for this. The `formatDate` function now converts the NgbDate to JSON, creates a new object from the JSON, and uses this to manually pass values into a new `moment()` after subtracting 1 from the month.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtrvjr-zkopwv

Function with the fix:

```
  formatDate(date: NgbDate) {

    // NgbDates use 1 for Jan, Moement uses 0, must substract 1 month for proper date conversion
    var ngbObj =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(date));
    var newMoment = moment();

    if (ngbObj) {
      ngbObj.month--;
      newMoment.month(ngbObj.month);
      newMoment.dates(ngbObj.day);
      newMoment.year(ngbObj.year);
    }

    // Convert date to "Mon Feb 01" format
    if (newMoment.isValid()) {
      return newMoment.format('ddd MMM DD');
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```