# How to convert Angular Date to new Date() in specific format?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I am using Angular 8 with ASP.net Core.

I installed ng-Bootstrap so I could get a nice DatePicker. For some reason, the DatePicker uses its own format that stores the Date like so.

StartDate: {year: 2019, month: 8, day: 31}

I need to create a new Date object and store the date like so.

StartDate: "2019-31-08"

This does not work.

```
var newDate = new Date(StartDate.getFullYearUtc(), StartDate.getMonthUtc(), Start.getDayUtc);
```

This does not work. It creates a weird looking date.

```
var newDate = new Date("2019-31-08");
```

This does not work. It wants to create a string.

```
var date = this.datePipe.transform(StartDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

This converts to string.

```
var newDate = new Date("2019-31-08").toISOString();
```

Does anyone know how to create a new Date object without converting to string?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, what a mess! I first had to use moment to even read the Date. I was then able to convert the ISO String to a Date my ASP.Net Core Web API could work with.

Converts to ISO String

```
var startDate = moment(content.StartDate).add(-1,'M').toISOString();
```

ISO String converted to Date

```
const newStartDate = moment(startDate, moment.defaultFormatUtc).toDate();
```

The Date is still not formatted like it was using the normal Angular Date object from a form, but at least ASP.Net can work with it.

Asp.Net Core Web API

```
Convert.ToDateTime(content.StartDate);
```

The Converts to ISO String method won't work with all the NgbDates. I modified this converter to work with Date. This seems to do the trick.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54078224

Answer (score -1):

`var newDate = new Date(2019, 7, 31);` will create a new date object with those values. Further info can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: This is from console.log. currentDate Tue Oct 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) Thanks for trying! Any other ideas?

Comment: @DanGorman think about the inputs. Month is zero based. Month  8 is September, not August. Change month from 8 to 7.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for the help. The Date is still in the wrong format. I'm getting the following HttpErrorResponse in Chrome. 0: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'StartDate', line 1, position 107."
1: "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: :. Path 'StartDate', line 1, position 113."
length: 2

Comment: @Dumber_Texan2 you should probably use something like StackBlitz to create a working example of the issue including the date picker and your specific data format to be able to troubleshoot further.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Will do! This was all working just fine when the Date was coming from a regular form. The ng-Boostrap DatePicker uses NgbDateStruct and it changes the Date from something like StartDate: "2019-31-08" to StartDate: {year: 2019, month: 8, day: 31}